# Foreach over a 2D Array in F# makes the compiler think the iterated values are of type object. Why?

Tags: .net, f#

I'm having trouble in this seemingly simple issue:

```
let xs = Array2D.init 3 3 (fun j i -> j*3 + i)
printfn "%O" (xs.GetType()) // prints System.Int32[,]

for v in xs do
    printfn "%d" v // <- this gives a compiler error. why should it?
```

The problem seems to be that F# thinks `v` is of type `obj`, which is kind of odd.

Is this a compiler bug or am I missing something perfectly obvious?

Thanks

Comment: I think this is due to some weirdness in .NET with the array types implementing `seq<'t>` weirdly.  Can you just use `Array2D.iter`?

Comment: Well, it seems like I'll have to, yes.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If we reflect into type `System.Int32[,]`, which `xs` is of, we may observe that it implements only non-generic [`System.Collections.IEnumerable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerable(v=vs.110).aspx) interface, so after desugaring

```
for v in xs do...
```

into its equivalent

```
let xe = xs.GetEnumerator()
while xe.MoveNext() do
    let v = xe.Current
    ...
```

we can see why `v` above is of type `obj` - this is the type of [System.Collections.IEnumerable.Current](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerator.current(v=vs.110).aspx) property.

**EDIT**: However, if explicitly cast `xs` type of `int[,]` to `seq<int>`, like below:

```
for v in Seq.cast<int> xs do
    printfn "%d" v
```

that is, `v` is now of type `int` and compiler is happy.

Comment: I see. That's ridiculous.

Comment: @devouredelysium Is it really ridiculous, weird, or simply language-specific that arrays of rank 1 implement `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<'T>` while arrays of other ranks do not?
I can't find it in the F# spec. While _6.5.6 Sequence Iteration Expressions_ provides for another way of determining the type of the elements than `System.Collections.IEnumerable.Current`, the indexer property required for this is only assumed by _6.4.6 Lookup Expressions_.